# Facebook Graph API getting friends

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am using the FB graph api to get a list of my friends' friends using:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<id>/friends?access_token=<token>
```

Now the weird thing is that this works for some of my friends and does not work for some others. Could somebody tell me why this is happening and a possible fix?

In cases where it does not work, I get the following message: "Can't lookup all friends of YYYYYY. Can only lookup for the logged in user (XXXXX), or friends of the logged in user with the appropriate permission"

And I repeat, I AM ABLE to get friend lists of some of my friends using the above URL. What permissions are being mentioned here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In new SDK of the Graph API is not possible to do that.

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-u).